# Expand string broken up into repeated, nested components

Tags: java, string, algorithm

I'm working on a problem, where given a string with substrings in paranthesis followed by values in curly brackets, the string expands by repeating the substring that number of times. So if you had (ab(d){3}){2} you'd get abdddabddd.

I feel like Im on the right track but that 1. this is pretty inefficient and 2. the tests seem to not return. Would love some help!

```
public class ExpandedString {
    public static String expandedString(String inputStr) {
        while (inputStr.contains("(")) {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputStr.length(); i++) {
                //check if there's something to repeat
                if (inputStr.charAt(i) == '{') {
                    int temp = i;
                    //find what you need to repeat
                    while (inputStr.charAt(temp) != '(') {
                        temp--;
                    }
                    String inputStr2 = inputStr.substring(i);
                    int numTimes = i + inputStr.indexOf("}");
                    //replace (blah) with blah times repeated numTimes
                    StringBuilder repeated = new StringBuilder(); 
                    for(int j = 0; j<numTimes;j++) {
                        repeated.append(inputStr.substring(temp + 1, i - 1));
                    }
                    inputStr.replace(inputStr.substring(temp, i), repeated.toString());
                    //start again
                    i = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return inputStr;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        // input for inputStr
        String inputStr = in .nextLine();

        String result = expandedString(inputStr);
        System.out.print(result);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please add a failing test-case the expected output, the actual output and debug-information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses a stack of StringBuilders and a current StringBuilder.

When a `(` is read, the current StringBuilder is pushed onto the stack and a new StringBuilder is created.

When a `)` is read, the multiplier `mul` is extracted, and the value of the current StringBuilder is appended `mul` times to the StringBuilder popped from the stack.

Otherwhise, append the char to the current StringBuilder.

```java
import java.util.Stack;

public class Expand
{
    public static String expand(String pattern)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Stack<StringBuilder> stack = new Stack<StringBuilder>();
        int len = pattern.length();
        int i = 0;
        while(i<len)
        {
            char c = pattern.charAt(i);
            if(c=='(')
            {
                stack.push(sb);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
            }
            else if(c==')')
            {
                String s = sb.toString();
                int k = pattern.indexOf('}', i);
                int mul = Integer.parseInt(pattern.substring(i+2, k));
                sb = stack.pop();
                for(int j=0;j<mul;j++)
                    sb.append(s);
                i = k;
            }
            else
                sb.append(c);
            i++;
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println(expand("(ab(d){3}){2}"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abdddabddd
```